# How to create a regex dynamically

Tags: javascript

How to create a regex dynamically:

I have the following regex, which has a hardcoded value `core.UI`, i want to use a variable instead.

```
test({
  storyKindRegex: /^core.UI$/,
})
```

I am now trying this, but it does not work

```
var value = 'core.UI'


    test({
          storyKindRegex: /${value }/,
        })
```

Comment: Create it from a string using `RegExp`. See the second example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

```js
//two utilities
const replace = (search, replacement) => haystack => String(haystack).replace(search, replacement);
const escapeRegex = replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');

//example
let str = "core.UI";
let regex = new RegExp("^" + escapeRegex(str) + "$");

console.log("string:", str);
console.log("Regex:", regex);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Btw, you forgot to escape the dot.